# Name of video with current date/time?

Tags: android, date, time, video-capture

I am new to android. i have video recording application where in i capture the video and store it, i need to store the video's name with the current date and time. so is there any way to do the same. Till i know the video names does not take the number format values..

```
String mediaFile;
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/VideoLogger");
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("VideoLogger", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss")
                .format(new Date());
        if (!sufix.equals("movie")) {
            mediaFile = mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "output_"
                    + timeStamp + "_" + sufix + ".txt";
        } else {
            mediaFile = mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "output_"
                    + timeStamp + ".mp4";

        }

        return mediaFile;
    }
}
```

Here is the code that i use for naming my video file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");//Give you current date
currentDate = date.format(new Date());SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");//Give you current time
currentTime = time.format(new Date());//Store like this
filename = currentDate +"-"+currentTime +".mp4";

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
Date date=new Date();
filename="/rec"+date.toString().replace(" ", "_").replace(":", "_")+".mp4";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss");
                        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
```

NOTE: you can change this: `"yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss"` to whatever you want, like `"yyyy_MM_dd_HH-mm-ss"`

EDIT: just in case you need to add this

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Comment: I need to store as a name for my video in the sdcard and some how it is not allowing me to play the video of that name.

Comment: i am not setting the values in the textview

Comment: Then the problem is not the name, but how you are saving your video.